# Washing Machine Agitates, But Won't Spin

Tags: washing-machine

My old top-loading Maytag washing machine (model no. LAT9304AA) won't spin clothes dry. It fills, agitates, and drains fine, but it won't spin -- at least not with wet clothes in it.

When I totally empty the machine, I can get it to spin. But it makes a banging noise and the basket appears to be off balance.

Some other clues:

- There's a burnt smell coming from the washer when in the spin cycle
- I checked the drain line and I don't see any signs of blockage
- I checked the lid switch and it works OK
- We have a cleaning lady that routinely overfills the machine

Any help would be appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out a sock had become wedged between the inner and outer tub. Once I removed it, the spin cycle worked fine. I guess the sock was enough to throw the balance off. Anyway, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have burned belt.  This machine when overloaded tends to throw clothing over the top of the tub.  Now this clothing will stop the inner tub from spinning by getting caught between the inner tub and the outer tub.  When this happens the belt cannot turn the inner tub so the belt starts to slip, thus the burning spell. I expect that you will need a new belt.  However, before all that you first need to clear the clothing stuck between the two tubs.  Watch the YouTube videos that give explanation to that model, not spinning, burning smell, belt service, slow spin and more.  P.